# Ok to update fragments instead of creating new instances?

Tags: android, android-activity, transactions, lifecycle, fragment

In the [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.html) on using fragments in the Android docs, when the application is in 'dualview' mode, the details fragment is recreated whenever the application needs to show details for a different title.  `FragmentTransaction.replace()` is used to swap out each old details fragment instance with a new one.

Is this recommended practice?  Isn't it wasteful to create a new UI instance when the real intent (no pun intended) is to update what the UI shows, not the UI itself.  It seems to me the only reason to create new instances is if one intends to add them to the backstack so the user can retrace steps.  Otherwise, is it safe/advisable to update a fragment directly?

In the case of the example, it would mean a method along the lines of `DetailsFragment.setShownIndex()`.  This would be called, passing in the new title index, instead of recreating `DetailsFragment`.

Suppose we have a version of the example where one activity manages both fragments, but only shows one at a time, swapping each fragment out as needed.  Would it be ok for the activity to create an instance of each fragment, retain references to each, and then simply add or remove these two instances from itself as needed?

One possibly sticky consequence of this would be that, when the titles fragment is in `resumed` state  (i.e. in the 'foreground'), selecting a title will result in a call to `DetailsFragment.setShownIndex()` at a time when the details fragment is in `stopped` state.

Good idea? Bad idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you said, the main reason to create new Fragment instances is for ease of using the back stack. It is also perfectly safe to reuse an existing Fragment (looking it up using either `FragmentManager.findFragmentById()` or `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`). Sometimes you'll need to make good use of the Fragment methods like `isVisible()`, `isRemoving()` etc. so you don't illegally reference UI components when the `DetailsFragment` is `stopped`.

Anyway in your proposed single-pane Activity with 2 fragments, your `setShownIndex` method could set a private field in `DetailsFragment` which is loaded in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`.

e.g.,

```
DetailsFragment df = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("details");
if (df != null) {
    df.setShownIndex(getSelectedIndex());
} else {
    df = DetailsFragment.newInstance(getSelectedIndex());
}
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, df, "details").commit();
```

In both cases, whether df is newly created or reused, `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` will be called when the `DetailsFragment` gets added to the container.

But if you want a back stack, I highly recommend just creating new instances, otherwise you're just implementing your own back stack for the contents of the `DetailsFragment`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code and it works for me :

```
private void replaceFragment(Class fragmentClass, String FRAGMENT_NAME, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String backStateName = fragmentClass.getName(); // nome della classe del Fragment

    Log.d("Fragment: ", "Creazione Fragment: "+backStateName);


    Boolean fragmentExit = isFragmentInBackstack(fragmentManager, backStateName);


    if (fragmentExit) { //Il Fragment è presente nello stacback

        // Fragment exists, go back to that fragment
        //// you can also use POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE flag, depending on flow
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(fragmentClass.getName(), 0);

    } else {

        // se non esiste lo aggiungiamo
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Inizializzo la transazione del Fragment
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(
                R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit);
        ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout_contentMain, fragment, FRAGMENT_NAME);
        ft.addToBackStack(fragmentClass.getName());
        ft.commit();

        // Recupero il numero di Fragment presenti
        Integer nFragment = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

        Log.d("Fragment: ", "Numero di Fragment: "+nFragment);

    }

}
```

To determine if the Fragment is already in StackBack execute this function :

```
public static boolean isFragmentInBackstack(final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager, final String fragmentTagName) {
    for (int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
        if (fragmentTagName.equals(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I Hope I could help you

Comment: would be more helpful if you provided comments in English

Comment: I'm sorry.i'm italian.